# How to Resolve "The operation has timed out" error

Tags: c#, winforms, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have a problem that while downloading the data it shows the error "The Operation has timed out".

What can i do to resolve this error? I am using Win forms(C#) here is my code please check it and give suggestions. Where should i change the code please help me...

```
  public void ProcessData()
        {


            try
            {
            string MessageTitle = "";
            int pages = Convert.ToInt32(txtPages.Text);

            for (int k = Count; k <= pages; k++)
            {

                string url = "http://www.yellowpages.com/" +StateName.ToLower()+ "/" + CategoryName + "?g=" + StateName + "&page=" + k + "&q=" + CategoryName + "";//txtYP.Text + k;
                System.Net.HttpWebRequest httpRequest;
                System.Net.HttpWebResponse httpResponse;
                System.IO.StreamReader SReader;
                string html;
                httpRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url));
                httpRequest.Method = "GET";
                httpResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)(httpRequest.GetResponse());
                SReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
                html = SReader.ReadToEnd();
                string strDummy = html;
                httpResponse.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

How long is it before the request times out?
Are you able to navigate to the url from a web browser?

Set `HttpWebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout` property on HttpWebRequest to a much higher value than what it is currently. The default value is 5 minutes. 
Not sure why it should take more than 5 minutes.

Instead of blocking on the getresponse, you could as well use async callbacks (`BeginGetResponse`/`EndGetResponse`).

**EDIT**

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true" />
  <sources>
    <source name="System.Net">
      <listeners>
        <add name="System.Net"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.Net.HttpListener">
      <listeners>
        <add name="System.Net"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
      <listeners>
        <add name="System.Net"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.Net.Cache">
      <listeners>
        <add name="System.Net"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add
      name="System.Net"
      type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
      initializeData="trace.log"
      traceOutputOptions = "ProcessId, DateTime"
            />
  </sharedListeners>
  <switches>
    <add name="System.Net"
         value="Verbose" />
    <add name="System.Net.Sockets"
         value="Verbose" />
    <add name="System.Net.Cache"
         value="Verbose" />
    <add name="System.Net.HttpListener"
         value="Verbose" />
  </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Add this section inside `configuration` section in the app.config of your application.
After adding the above, rebuild the solution and run it.
Look at the trace.log written in the bin directory of your application for more details.

Comment: Thank you for giving response ,,,yes i able to navigate the url from web browser...how to set Httprequest time  please helpme....where i can write code...

Comment: why it is showing this error " The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly."

Comment: It seems to me you are hammering a site you don't own with requests and are getting blocked by their firewall\bot countermeasures.

Comment: Not sure what the exact reason for the failure. You need to look at the stack trace. Look under the "EDIT" section in my answer as to how to enable tracing.

Comment: Hi Vijay Singari..... actually i'm using winforms.so,there is no app.config file....

Comment: You should add it. Right-click on the sln, select Add -> Add New Item. Click on the Application Configuration item.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code :

**httpRequest.Timeout** = 3600000;

this will increase the request timeout to one hour.

Comment: Hi thank you for giving respose ...actually we don't know how much time it will take it may be either 5hrs or 7hrs.....

Comment: then put it 10 hours, some programs have almost 24 hours as timeout for their requests. so its well tested.

Answer (score 0):

I have face same issue while executing my console application on server. Below solution work for me :

Uncheck the automatic configuration script under Lan settings in internet option and check the automatic detect settings.
It resolve my problem for operation time out error .